# Edit text in an Excel column without deleting the current content

Tags: excel

I'm at work and this is my first time using Excel.
I have the following question:
When I want to edit text in a column, I can press Enter or Spacebar to do so without using the mouse.
However, this way the whole text gets deleted.

Now, I want to edit text while keeping the text in the current column.
(And, yes, I'm definitely too lazy to use the mouse.)

Thank you very much, everybody. :)

Comment: Press F2 (edit). Btw, pressing Enter doesn't delete the contents of the cell it think. :) It moves to the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAvigate to the cell you want and then press "F2" key, this will allow you to edit the text in the selected cell. Just change and press enter!